# Getting attributed html String too from UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I add a attributed text in text view using code given bellow

```
NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src=\"%@\">",sticker.image_url];
NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
self.textView.attributedText=attrStr;
```

the textview has text `testing <img src="www.google.com">`

above code show image in text view. But now the problem is i want to get string and need to do some more work on it. Thats why when i try to get attributed string from text view using code given below then it only gives text  not the html code that i added in the text view.

```
[self.textview.attributedString string]
return text = testing
```

Any help please. Acutally i want to show some images using html in text and then need to upload that code on server.

i am unable to understand where that html text goes away, it should stay be some where in the text but i am unable to get that text back
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Read the docs. `attributedText` would hold your attributed string, not `text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you convert html text to attributed string then you cannot get it back, I save a copy of text in 2nd variable for later use.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `self.textView.text` because what you'll have is just the plain text, at the same time you cannot use `self.textView.attributedText` since what you'll have is just the NSAttributedString object, that is the representation of what you built using

```
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:yourData options:yourOptions documentAttributes:nil error:nil];`
```

NSAttributedString is not built with html representation in mind, what you used is just a way to easily create a NSAttributedString starting from html, but there is not a complete support between the 2 representations.

You need something slightly more complex that can accomplish this thing, you may want to check this repo
https://github.com/IdeasOnCanvas/Ashton

In particular I'm referring to category `NSAttributedString+Ashton.h` that has this cool method

```
// Attributed String with CT Attributes
- (NSString *)mn_HTMLRepresentationFromCoreTextAttributes;
```

I'm not sure about the html tags that the implementation supports, but it is a start anyway.

If your intent is just to save the html that you set for later use, you could subclass `NSAttributedString`, adding a new property `NSString *html` that you will set overriding `initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:` Obviously it doesn't scale well, but it is a 'dirty' solution in the short run.

Comment: DLog(@"%@",[self.textView.attributedText string]); it is not returning me html string that is in text view.

Comment: and how can i get that html string representation back from uitextview?

Comment: Import the category, use the category. `[self.textView.attributedText mn_HTMLRepresentationFromCoreTextAttributes];`

Comment: this is not a solution for my question. and it is not working for me

Comment: I see how it doesn't solve completely your problem, but it is really what you need to look into. Using the abstraction that Ashton implements, you'll be able to accomplish what you need, it likely doesn't support any html tag, so you need to look into and see what you can do to expand it.